# A centered column without fixed width

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to create a page with a centred column, in which the individual items do not have a fixed width (see image).

I've tried using flexbox, but that seems to want to fill out the blocks over the entire box. I've also tried to use the normal `margin: 0 auto` approach, but that doesn't work if you don't have a fixed width.

Is there a way to do this? I prefer pure CSS of course.

[image: example blocks]

Comment: What do you mean by "do not have a fixed width"? Could you provide some html/css code of what you tried that didn't work with flexbox? Are these items images or divs? This looks like something flexbox could easily do.

This site is helpful for learning flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: What determines the width in your graphical example for the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). No width settings anywhere.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.element {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: thin solid blue;
}

span:not(first-child) {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  border: thin solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">This is text</div>
  <div class="element">This is also some text</div>
  <div class="element">
    <span>And even in different</span>
    <span>boxes on the same row</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, hope it will help ^^ :

```css
.parent {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.child {
  margin-bottom:20px;
  min-width:200px;
  min-height:80px;
  background-color:#555;
}

.child-fluid {
  min-width:100%;
  display:flex;
  padding:5px;
}

.content {
  min-height:80px;
  background-color:#AAA;
  flex:1;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child" style="min-width: 350px;"></div>
        <div class="child child-fluid">
         <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

with flex box you have to have a width set on the parent. It doesn't have to be  a fixed width though you could do something like

```
    .parent{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
       }
```

that might work.